# Getting directory of a file in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a requirement where I need to copy some files from one location to other (Where the file may exist). While doing so,

1. I need to take a backup if the file already exists.
2. Copy the new file to the same location

I am facing problem in point 2. While I am trying to get the destination path for copying files, I am unable to extract the directory of the file. I tried using various options of `find` command, but was unable to crack it.
I need to trim the file name from the full file path so that it can be used in `cp` command. I am new to shell scripting. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
cp --backup
```

> `-b'`--backup[=METHOD]'
>        *Note Backup options::.  Make a backup of each file that would
>        otherwise be overwritten or removed.  As a special case, `cp'
>        makes a backup of SOURCE when the force and backup options are
>        given and SOURCE and DEST are the same name for an existing,
>        regular file.  One useful application of this combination of
>        options is this tiny Bourne shell script:
>
> ```
>       #!/bin/sh
>       # Usage: backup FILE...
>       # Create a GNU-style backup of each listed FILE.
>       for i; do
>         cp --backup --force -- "$i" "$i"
>       done
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but when I am using -b, I am getting error that "b" is not a recognized flag.

Comment: Install GNU `cp` from coreutils

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the filename, why not do a

```
basename /root/wkdir/index.txt
```

and assign it to a variable which would return only the filename?

Comment: mani and dtmilano: Thanks for your responses. Found another way of doing it, I am now using `dirname` command to extract the file directory.